# Is a transit visa required in Tehran for only flight transfer?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, iran

I am travelling from Dusseldorf to Delhi and vice versa via Tehran. Airlines is same (Mahan airlines). I will not get out of the airport in Tehran. Do I need a transit visa in Tehran? I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: What citizenship are you?

Comment: In an answer that has since been deleted, they indicated that they are an Indian citizen. I have added this information to the question and updated the tags, so it should now be answerable.

Comment: Best is to ask your airliner as conditions in those regions constantly changes.

Answer (score 2):

Tehran allow citizens of India to transit airside through the airport without obtaining a visa, as long as the stay is less than 24 hours.  Using a Transit-without-visa (TWOV) you will not be allow leave the airside area of the airport.

Interestingly, if you are connecting on a different airline and require bags to be re-checked (something that would normally require passing through immigration), Tehran airport has a free service where they will handle that for you so that you do not need to pass through immigration.

It is also possible to apply for a transit visa on arrival, which allows staying up to 48 hours.

Not directly related to your question, however if you ever intend to visit the US, I would recommend against getting a visa and entering Iran if possible.  For citizens of countries that are eligible to use the US Visa Waiver Program, entering Iran will invalidate that eligibility.  For an Indian citizen a US visa would be required anyway, but having to list that you have visited Iran may make the process of obtaining that visa more difficult.

Simply transiting through the country should not be an issue, as that is generally not regard as having visited the country.

Comment: The 48-hour visa isn't mentioned in Timatic, so airlines will not board an Indian with separate tickets without a visa

Comment: @Coke They will, because a visa is NOT required, even when travelling with separate tickets, even with checks bags.  Getting an airline to agree may require some effort, but I suspect most airlines that fly to Tehran are aware of this arrangement. (Google will find you further details on this process, but it's not relevant to this question)

Comment: IME, they aren't aware about this for any country. I've seen Europeans at ZRH, FMM and ARN being summarily and clearly denied boarding on flights to Russia and China for pure transit, only because their tickets were separate. So while you're technically correct, convincing ground personnel will be hard *if you're lucky*. And as for "I suspect most airlines that fly to Tehran are aware of this arrangement", note that it's usually not airline staff that checks you in, but outsourced ground staff

Comment: @Coke And yet, Google will find you countless reports of people doing this without any problems.  Go figure.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country within 24 hours

So if the trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa.

If it's on separate tickets, it is also possible if the transit airport has facilities to transfer your luggage, but the check-in staff at the departure airport may well not be aware of this, and consequently deny you boarding.

If you're on separate tickets, contact the ground handling agent at your departure airport responsible for Mahan airlines and ask for their interpretation of the rules